# Vuetify - Get object's single property on v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a form with Vuetify, which has initial values on some inputs and these values come from objects. 
Basically, the objects have two important properties: the `name` and the `id`. Folllowing the Vuetify docs, i'm using `item-text` prop to display the object's name on the **v-select** and `item-value` to return the object's id when the option is selected. When another option is selected, it returns the id as expected. However, if the initial option is not changed, the returned value is the whole object, instead of just the id.

The context is this:

```
       <v-select
          label="Select an specialty..."
          v-model="entry.specialty"
          :items="specialties"
          :item-text="item=>item.name"
          :item-value="item=>item.id"
        ></v-select>
```

The **entry** object has the **specialty** property and the initial specialty's name is displayed on the select. I think the problem is the **v-model**, which has the whole specialty object. I tried to set the v-model as `entry.specialty.id`, but it did not work as expected.

Let me know if there's more information i can give.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the property `return-object`:

```
<v-select
  label="Select an specialty..."
  v-model="entry.specialty"
  :items="specialties"
  :item-text="item=>item.name"
  :item-value="item=>item.id"
  :return-object="false"
/>
```

The `return-obejct` can be: `true` or `false`

If this don't work, please post whole component code.

Comment: Rie is right, it's already returning the id when I select an option. The problem is when  I don't. I haven't found any solution yet, but solved my problem calling another API service with a slightly different data strucute.